# Projection of non-regular polyhedron onto graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Regular polyhedrons are planar graphs but are non-regular polyhedrons also planar such that Euler's formula V - E + F = 2 applies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you are limiting yourself to convex (but not necessarily regular) polyhedra.  The surface of any convex polyhedron is equivalent to a planar graph by taking away a face and expanding the remaining vertices and edges to a flattened configuration.  In this form Euler's famous formula holds, provided the unbounded region of the plane is counted as a "face".

Here's a recent "featured AMS column" by Joseph Malkevitch on [Euler's Polyhedral Formula](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-eulers-formula) which chooses convex 3D polyhedra as the setting (and mentions some of the excluded figures alluded to in Gerry's and my comments below).

Comment: You have to be quite careful how you define polyhedron to get the formula to apply. I think "non-self-intersecting" isn't enough. You can't have, say, two cubes that meet along an edge, you can't have a cube with an indentation in it that makes for a non-simply-connected face, and so on. Just how tricky it is to get the definition right is explored at length in the delightful book by Lakatos, Proofs and Refutations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, good point.  We also cannot have "polyhedra" with holes in them.  I probably should restrict my discussion to convex (but not necessarily regular) polyhedra for the sake of precision.